# Github Actions workflow CD with rsync : provide only the needed list of files since the last deployment

Tags: github-actions

I have a CD process living within a GHA workflow. This workflow used an rsync mechanism. Since the repo is checkout within the workflow runner, it's impossible for rsync to only files based on a give timestamp. I don't want to compare my copied repo with the code on my target, it's time consuming (the repo is ~1.5Go).

So I'm looking for a simple solution to get the last commit used (without any error) used by the last execution of the current workflow on a given branch. My idea is to generate on Github the list of files used by rsync to limit the files send to the target.

If you have a better idea to solve this, you're welcome !

Comment: See my answer here for a similar way we do on GitLab - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67563131/skip-gitlab-pipeline-job-if-no-changes-in-files-and-last-pipeline-for-that-job-i/67563919#67563919 - essentially the idea is you store last commit details on Reliza Hub and then request from it using api key.